# Storm Pacemaker with upgraded KafkaSpout

Tags: apache-storm

I had a question regarding the usage of Pacemaker. We have a currently running Storm cluster on 1.0.2 and are in the process of migrating it to 1.2.2. We also use KafkaSpout to consume data from the KAfka topics. 
Now, since this release in for Kafka 0.10 +, most of the load from ZK would be taken off since the offsets won't be stored in ZK.

Considering this, does it make sense for us to also start looking at Pacemaker to reduce load further on ZK?

Our cluster has 70+ supervisor and around 70 workers with a few unused slots. Also, we have around 9100+ executors/tasks running.

Another question I have is regarding the heartbeats and who all send it to whom? From what I have read, workers and supervisors send their heartbeats to ZK, which is what Pacemaker alleviates. How about the tasks? Do they also send heartbeats? If yes, then is it to ZK or where else? There's this config called **task.heartbeat.frequency.secs** which has led me to some more confusion.

The reason I ask this is that if the task level heartbeats aren't being sent to ZK, then its pretty evident that Pacemaker won't be needed. This is because with no offsets being committed to ZK, the load would be reduced dramatically. Is my assesment correct or would Pacemaker be still a feasible option? Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Pacemaker](http://storm.apache.org/2016/04/12/storm100-released.html) is an optional Storm daemon designed to process heartbeats from workers, which is implemented as a in-memory storage. You could use it if ZK become a bottleneck because the storm cluster scaled up
2. `supervisor` report heartbeat to `nimbus`that it is alive, used for failure tolerance, and the frequency is set via **supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs**, **stored in ZK**.

   And `worker` should heartbeat to the `supervisor`, the frequency is set via **worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs**. These heartbeats are stored in **local file system**.
3. **task.heartbeat.frequency.secs**: How often a task（executor) should heartbeat its status to the master(Nimbus), it <strike>never take effect in storm, and</strike>  has been deprecated for Storm v2.0 RPC heartbeat reporting

   This heartbeat stats what executors are assigned to which worker, **stored in ZK**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From, what I understand, all the components like supervisors, workers send their heartbeats to ZK from where it is picked up by Nimbus. By your definition of task.heartbeat.frequency.secs, looks like even task level heartbeats also go to ZK. Is that correct? Also, what did you mean by task level heartbeats never take effect in storm?

Comment: <Continuing from above comment coz of character limits> : With pacemaker, that will go away and it will pushed to an in-memory storage and Nimbus would directly pick from there, thereby offloading ZK from this. Also, we are in the process of evaluation whether we should switch over to Pacemaker or not and was trying to understand of ZK can become bottleneck with our current setup. Note that our targeted storm version is 1.2.2, so have task level heartbeats been disabled in that version also?

Comment: Overall you are right. However, as far as I know, there is no task level heartbeats at all, **task.heartbeat.frequency.secs** is never used. In storm 2.0, there is a new executor metric heartbeat.

Comment: Aah ok. Then I think looking at our setup, ZK shouldn't really be a bottleneck since the newer version of Kafka anyways doesn't push the offsets to ZK. Thanks a lot @Jacky. I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Sagar sorry, I made a stupid mistake. in version before 2.0, the Worker is written in clojure, I missed it. There are task-level (executor level) heartbeats, stats what executors are assigned to this worker and they are stored in ZK.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying that. So, essentially every 3-5s, these 9000+ executors would be sending their heartbeats to ZK. In that case, it would be helpful to look at the metrics and actually consider an option like Pacemaker then. One last piece of info if you can provide, what are the metrics that I should actually look at? Some of the things are network throughput, average requests per sec(across the network), txps and bytes per sec? I assume these need to be across the network? Also, any ZK specific metrics?